# how to find and insert data auto incremented in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
# employee_code, name
TJU_741,        Sanjjev Kumar
TJU_856,        Akshay Mehta
GUEST_1,        ajay@gmail.com
GUEST_2,        x@yahoo.com
```

this is my Employee Table i have to insert data in such manner Like GUEST_2 is there now if we insert another value as  then employee_code should insert GUEST_3... 
please tell me how to find  that GUEST_2 and we can add 1 i dont insert mannualy  it should automatic incremented

```
 insert into employee (employee_code,name) values ('GUEST_3','xyz')
```

this query i am executing please suggest me

Comment: add another colomn for id with auto increment field with primary key

Comment: See normalization. Store 'guest' and '2' in separate columns

Comment: how to serate column please  how u will find last inserted data so that i can Split and incremental value

Comment: search for REPLACE() and CAST() functions

Comment: that is ok But one thing i want to know how i will find Last inserted data GUEST_2 so that i will SPlit and i will add in +1 and cast and then we will insert

Answer (score 1):

**Follow The Steps:**

**Step 1: Create a Table**

```
create table employee (
emp_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
employee_code varchar(50) not null,
name varchar(50) not null
);
```

**Step 2:Insert Record**

```
insert into employee (employee_code,name) values ('GUEST','ABC');
insert into employee (employee_code,name) values ('GUEST','AAA');
insert into employee (employee_code,name) values ('GUEST','BBB');
insert into employee (employee_code,name) values ('GUEST','CCC');
insert into employee (employee_code,name) values ('GUEST','DDD');
```

**Step 3: Use Concat() Method**

```
select CONCAT(employee_code,'_',emp_id) as employee_code ,name from employee;
```

**Step 4:Your Output:**

[image]

I Hope You Find Your Right Solution Here..